# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...? PHP Specific

Tags: php

Getting this warning when trying to run my local PHP project (index.php):

```
Warning: require_once(/Controller/BulletinController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEBB_SERVER/6.2.1x/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Controller/BulletinController.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEBB_SERVER/6.2.1x/index.php on line 2
```

No such file or directory? This is my first 6 rows in index.php:

```
   <?php
   require_once ("/Controller/BulletinController.php");
   require_once ("/General/MasterPage.php");
   require_once ("./General/dbConnection.php");

   session_start();
```

I've tried giving BulletinController.php 777 rights (just developing locally), but no luck.

This is what my structure looks like, so everything is in place:

[image: This is what my structure looks like]

Thankful for any advice you may have.

Comment: file\directory permissions?

Comment: What do you mean? Should I activate 777 permissions in terminal for the whole folder/all files?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require_once ("/Controller/BulletinController.php");
```

must be

```
require_once ("Controller/BulletinController.php");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not cut it. Thanks anyway, will keep looking for other solutions, let me know if you have any other idea. It just says:

Comment: Warning: require_once(/settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEBB_SERVER/6.2.1x/General/dbConnection.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/settings.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEBB_SERVER/6.2.1x/General/dbConnection.php on line 2

Comment: I wrote this answer to show that the slash '/' at the beginning of the path is the problem. It points to the root path of the server. Now, settings.php path needs correction.   When the path begins without the slash is the relative path to the file where the require statement lies.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the whole path:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . "/Controller/BulletinController.php";
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Still got an error though, now it says;

Fatal error: Undefined constant '__FILE\__' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEBB_SERVER/6.2.1x/index.php on line 2

Comment: Other variant is to use basename(__DIR__)  instead of  dirname(__FILE__)

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately, will keep trying to solve the prob. Thanks alot anyway Teddy!

Comment: Warning: require_once(DIR/Controller/BulletinController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEBB_SERVER/6.2.1x/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DIR/Controller/BulletinController.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/WEBB_SERVER/6.2.1x/index.php on line 2